# Google Sheets: display all values existing in column A when a specific string exist elsewhere on that row

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I want to display all values existing in column A when a specific string exist elsewhere on that row.

The formula in B10 should display "Table, Bed" in any form.
[image: Table]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",",IF(C3:E5=A10,A3:A5,)))
```

Comparison `=` within a array formula  produces the desired array. Join them with `,`